# High CPU usage was detected for the kudu app for Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-plans

I noticed that our app was experiencing high CPU usage. In the diagnostics I found the below message.

High CPU usage was detected for the kudu app for 'DemoApiApp'(39.1%) on only one instance out of 4 instances in your app service plan. The affected instance had a peak overall usage of 87.8% during this time. High CPU usage in the kudu process is most often caused by web job usage. Affected instance name: RD0003FF1C445A