# What would cause high KUDU usage (and eventual 502 errors) on an Azure App Service Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, kudu

We have a number of API apps and WebApps on an Azure App Service P2v2 instance. We've been experiencing an amount of platform instability: the App Service becomes unhealthy and we get a rash of 502 errors across various of the Apps (different ones each time), attributable to very high CPU and Memory usage on the app service. We've tried scaling all the way up to P3v2, but whatever the issue is seems eventually to consume all resources available.

Whenever we've been able to trace a culprit among the apps, it has turned dout not to be the app itself but the Kudu service related to it.

A sample error message is `High physical memory usage detected on multiple occasions. The kudu process for the app [sitename]'pe-services-color' is the most common cause of high memory usage. The most common cause of high memory usage for the kudu process is web jobs.` where the actual app whose Kudu service is named changes quite frequently.

What could be causing the Kudu services to consume so much CPU/Memory, and what can we do to stabilise this app service?

Is it simply that we have too many apps running on one plan? This seems unlikely since all these apps ran previously on a single classic cloud service instance, but if so, what are the limits for apps and slots on a single plan?

(I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49053245/1014822) but the answer doesn't help)

**Update**
From Azure support, these are apparently the limits on Small - Medium - Large non-shared app services:

> Worker Size     Max sites
>
> Small              5 Medium             10 Large              20

- with 'sites' comprising app services/api apps and their slots.

They seem ridiculously low, and make the larger App Service units highly uneconomic. Can anyone confirm these numbers?

(Incidentally, we found that turning off Always On across the board fixed the issue - it was only causing a problem on *empty* sites though - we haven't had a chance yet to see if performance is good with all the sites filled.)

Comment: Kudu is another site and using memory/cpu when serving requests/webjobs.   Are you doing any deployment (this is done via one API of Kudu)?  Are you running webjob (whcih is running on Kudu)?   Are you using debug console (again API calls to Kudu)?  ...

Comment: No, no debugging and no webjobs. The fails do seem worse for a few hours *after* a deployment, but not during.

Comment: I found a related post in TechNet that referenced this GitHub post:  https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2351. Do your web apps come with many files that need indexing?

Answer (score -2):

High CPU and memory utilization would be mostly caused by your program/code itself. If there are lot of CPU intensive tasks and you applied lot of parallel programming that spawn lot of new threads can contribute to high cpu and memory utilization. So review your code and see such instances. When number of parallel threads increased cpu utilization goes high and it starts scaling up frequently that adds up your cost also sometime thread loss and unexpected results. As Azure resources costs are high you need to plan your performance accordingly.
You can monitor this using the Metrics option of the app service plan in the blade .