# Disable Kudu tool for web app in Azure App service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, kudu

Kudu is taking more than 90% of CPU. Is it possible to completely disable the Kudu tool?[image]

Comment: Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.appservice.websitedata.scmsitealsostopped?view=azure-dotnet-preview). This is for a stopped website.

Comment: Even you can add Application Settings with key `WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION` with value `true`,  in `Azure App` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings`

Comment: I have added the key-value `WEBSITE_DIABLE_SCM_SEPERATION`, got the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec0ZH.png) when I try to access scm.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958548/what-would-cause-high-kudu-usage-and-eventual-502-errors-on-an-azure-app-servi

Comment: What is the framework and how you are deploying your app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `KUDU` Console => `Process Explorer`, we can see option for SCM.

[image]

- I have added  `WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION` key with value `true` in Azure Application Settings.

[image]

I can see the SCM in `Process Explorer` is not visible

[image]

We can restrict the access to KUDU or SCM in `Networking` Section of the Azure App Service.

- Navigate to `Azure Portal` => Your `Azure Web App Service` => select `Networking` under `Settings` section.
- Under `Inbound Traffic`, select `Access restriction`.

[image]

- Select `WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net` tab and click `+` `Add rule`.
- Under `source settings` => in `IP Address Block` , provide the set of IP Address which you want to block the SCM.

[image]

- When I try to access the SCM URL, I got the below error.
  [image]

References taken from Doc [1](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#enabledisable-build-actions) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-best-practices#net)